# repo sync -j2 asks for authentication for GitHub, fails

Tags: android, github, repository

So I downloaded the OmniROM KitKat source, and created a local manifest file with my device source and other required sources (http://github.com/TamsuiCM11) After running a `repo sync -j2`, everything seems to sync fine, until this:

```
Fetching projects:  99% (425/429)  Fetching project platform/external/chromium_org/third_party/openssl
^CUsername for 'https://github.com': NSDCars5
Password for 'https://NSDCars5@github.com': 
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/TamsuiCM11/android_frameworks_opt_telephony/' not found
error: Cannot fetch TamsuiCM11/android_frameworks_opt_telephony
aborted by user
```

Googling says to use SSH, but I don't see where; in `repo init`? I used git:// for that.

I have tried to sync with -j1, -j2, -j4, -j8, and -j16. Every time it's the same thing. The system is VirtualBox, with Ubuntu 13.10 x64, 4 GB of RAM, no swap, and NAT for networking.

EDIT: The repo init command I used was `repo init -u git://github.com/omnirom/android.git -b android-4.4`, and my local manifest is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest>

        <!-- Dependancies -->
        <project path="device/sony/tamsui-common" name="TamsuiCM11/android_device_sony_tamsui-common" remote="github" revision="cm-11.0" />
        <project path="kernel/sony/msm7x27a" name="TamsuiCM11/android_kernel_sony_msm7x27a" remote="github" revision="master" />
        <project path="device/sony/qcom-common" name="CyanogenMod/android_device_sony_qcom-common" remote="github" revision="cm-11.0"/>
        <project path="device/sony/common" name="CyanogenMod/android_device_sony_common" remote="github" revision="cm-11.0"/>
        <project path="kernel/sony/nanhu_ds" name="TamsuiCM11/android_kernel_sony_msm7x27a-nanhu" remote="github" revision="cm-11.0" />

        <!-- Devices -->
        <project path="device/sony/nanhu_ds" name="TamsuiCM11/android_device_sony_nanhu_ds" remote="github" revision="cm-11.0" />

        <!-- Proprietary files -->
        <project path="vendor/sony" name="TamsuiCM11/proprietary_vendor_sony" remote="github" revision="cm-10.2" />

        <!-- Drivers -->
        <project path="hardware/qcom/display-legacy" name="TamsuiCM11/android_hardware_qcom_display-legacy" remote="github" revision="cm-11-jlo" />
        <project path="hardware/qcom/audio-legacy" name="TamsuiCM11/android_hardware_qcom_audio-legacy" remote="github" revision="cm-11.0" />
        <project path="hardware/qcom/media-legacy" name="TamsuiCM11/android_hardware_qcom_media-legacy" remote="github" revision="cm-11.0" />

        <!-- Forked CM repos -->
        <project path="system/core" name="TamsuiCM11/android_system_core" groups="pdk" remote="github" revision="stable/cm-11.0" />
        <project path="hardware/libhardware_legacy" name="TamsuiCM11/android_hardware_libhardware_legacy" groups="pdk" remote="github" revision="stable/cm-11.0" />
        <project path="frameworks/opt/telephony" name="TamsuiCM11/android_frameworks_opt_telephony" groups="pdk" remote="github" revision="stable/cm-11.0" />        
</manifest>
```

Comment: https://github.com/TamsuiCM11/android_frameworks_opt_telephony/ is not a valid Github repository, and based on the information you've given it's not clear why Repo attempts to fetch it. What's in your local manifest? What manifest URL did you pass to `repo init`?

Comment: @MagnusBäck Edited OP to include both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your local manifest asks Repo to fetch https://github.com/TamsuiCM11/android_frameworks_opt_telephony, but that simply isn't a valid repository. I note that a [recent commit](https://github.com/TamsuiCM11/local_manifest/commit/db0b37425b2d650fb26eacd0dfb9bbc45b576b47) in https://github.com/TamsuiCM11/local_manifest deletes the reference to that git (with a commit message indicating that it's no longer necessary), and maybe the git itself was removed too. I suggest you update your local manifest from said git.

(I notice that your local manifest as listed in the question lacks `<remove-project>` tags. I'm surprised that you were able to start syncing with those missing, but those lines *are* included in the upstream local manifest that you at some point copied.)

Comment: Thanks! Yes, it lacks the removing tags, because it wouldn't sync with those there - I just assumed they weren't present in Omni. Repo synced successfully!

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  Indeed, in my case I had the `name` attribute set to be the same as the `path` attribute, which is not a valid git repo.  I needed `name` to be the github org/project.  So

`<remote  name="github" fetch="https://github.com/" />
<project path="toolchain/llvm-project" name="llvm/llvm-project"               
             remote="github" clone-depth="1" />`